# Python apk with kivy and buildozer including PySCF

Tags: python, android, kivy, apk

I have problems trying to include PySCF on my kivy app when I try to compile it to an apk with buildozer: It seems the problem is related to including lapack, where android.ndk should be r21e for including gfortran and that kind of stuff, but when I specify this version I get another error which says I need a version of ndk ≥ 25.
I don't know what else to do, please do you know how to solve this? I'm starting developing apps so it should be something easy I guess...